# How to improve Azure Custom Vision accuracy

Tags: azure, machine-learning, image-classification

We have a POC where we need to identify a person from a given photo.
We are using Azure Custom Vision.
We have already trained the models, each person has around 400 images, with rotated 0,90, 180 and 270 degrees.
But when we try to predict from new photos, it detects the incorrect tags with more accuracy than the correct one.
We have even tried with Object Detection and creating the bounding boxes on faces manually.
What could we do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The following is a general pattern to help you train a more accurate model:

1. First-round training
2. Add more images and balance data; retrain
3. Add images with varying background, lighting, object size, camera angle, and style; retrain
4. Use new image(s) to test prediction
5. Modify existing training data according to prediction results

Comment: Thanks, one question, I'm very new to machine learning, so still lots to learn, isn't the retrained required only when the images for retrain were not know before? I mean in my scenario, all of the Images I'm adding for training I already know from which person they are, so they have been automatically tagged with the correct values.